# Prove that $I$ is a left ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring. Let $z$ be a fixed element of $R$ and $J$ be an ideal of $R$. Define $I = \{r\in R|rz \in J\}$. Prove that $I$ is a left ideal of $R$.

**My Attempt** $I \neq \emptyset$, since $0_R\cdot z = 0_R \in J \Rightarrow 0_R \in I$

Let, $x,y \in J \Rightarrow x = az$ and $y = bz,$ where $a,b \in R \Rightarrow x - y = az - bz = (a-b)z \in J.$ Thus, $x-y \in I.$

$rx = r(az) = (ra)z \in J.$ Thus, $rx \in I.$

Therefore, $I$ is a left ideal of $R$. Do you think my proof is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are a little off on the defining characteristic of $I$.  If $x\in I$, then $xz\in J$.  So, you start with $x,y\in R$ such that $xz,yz\in J$.  Then
$$
(x-y)z=xz-yz.
$$
Since both $xz,yz\in J$ and $J$ is an ideal, $xz-yz\in J$.  Thus $x-y\in I$.  Do something similar for the last part.

Comment: I am slightly confused. In another proof, which was to show that $J$ is a left ideal of $R$, we had to define the elements of $J$ by letting $x = az$ and $y=bz$. Then, could you please explain why is it different in here?

Comment: @abcd1234 You prove something is an ideal by showing that its criteria for membership satisfy the properties of an ideal.  My guess is that $J$ was defined to be the ideal generated by an element $z\in R$.  Then everything in $J$ looks like $az$ for some $a\in R$.

Comment: @abcd1234 Everything seems correct to me as written.

Comment: Sorry to keep commenting, but could you please explain why did you start with $(x-y)z = xz - yz$ but not $xz - yz = (x-y)z$?

Comment: @abcd1234 In order to show that $x-y\in I$, you need to show that it satisfies the defining characteristic, namely that $(x-y)z\in J$.